# Android - How to swipe the tab in TabLayout using Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have the four Tabs in a fragment. I am loading data into RecyclerView.. I am not using each fragment for each tab and am using single fragment for all Tabs. I just changed data set only in the Adapter. While selecting tab its loading that data so its working good and well. Now I want to swipe the page it should go to next tab...

```
public class CreateFlipFragment extends Fragment {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private StickerListAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Sticker> stickerList;
private ViewPager viewPagerStickers;

public CreateFlipFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_flip_new, container, false);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout_flips);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_flips_sticker);
    viewPagerStickers = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vp_stickers);

    stickerList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new StickerListAdapter(stickerList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    setupTab();

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        viewPagerStickers.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    loadStickers1();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    loadStickers2();

                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    loadStickers4();

                    break;
                case 3:
                    loadStickers5();

                    break;
                default:
                    stickerList.clear();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
   }

   private void setupTab() {
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab());
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.meme0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.bubble0);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_sticker_text_off);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_sticker_image_off);
   }

   private void loadStickers1() {
    stickerList.clear();
    stickerList.add(new Sticker(null, R.drawable.word4, Sticker.STICKER_TYPE.STICKER));
    stickerList.add(new Sticker(null, R.drawable.word5, Sticker.STICKER_TYPE.STICKER));
    stickerList.add(new Sticker(null, R.drawable.word6, Sticker.STICKER_TYPE.STICKER));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   private void loadStickers2() {
    stickerList.clear();
    stickerList.add(new Sticker(null, R.drawable.word4, Sticker.STICKER_TYPE.STICKER));
    stickerList.add(new Sticker(null, R.drawable.word5, Sticker.STICKER_TYPE.STICKER));
    stickerList.add(new Sticker(null, R.drawable.word6, Sticker.STICKER_TYPE.STICKER));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   private void loadStickers3() {
    stickerList.clear();
    stickerList.add(new Sticker(null, R.drawable.word4, Sticker.STICKER_TYPE.STICKER));
    stickerList.add(new Sticker(null, R.drawable.word5, Sticker.STICKER_TYPE.STICKER));
    stickerList.add(new Sticker(null, R.drawable.word6, Sticker.STICKER_TYPE.STICKER));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   private void loadStickers4() {
    stickerList.clear();
    stickerList.add(new Sticker(null, R.drawable.word4, Sticker.STICKER_TYPE.STICKER));
    stickerList.add(new Sticker(null, R.drawable.word5, Sticker.STICKER_TYPE.STICKER));
    stickerList.add(new Sticker(null, R.drawable.word6, Sticker.STICKER_TYPE.STICKER));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
  }
```

fragment_create_flip_new.xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout_flips"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray_very_light"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabDefalt"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/text_color" />

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_flips_sticker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent" />

     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vp_stickers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

</LinearLayout>
```

Everything working fine... now i want add swipe the page it goes to next tab and change that data set... Help me... Thanks in advance...

Comment: you need to attach view pager with tab layout for swiping tab

Comment: ya i tried. In viewPager adaper having so many fragment so you can add fragment for each tab. but in my case i am using single fragment and just changed set only so how handle the swipe page..??

Comment: you can add same fragment in view pager with different data in recyclerview

Comment: Okay... Where to add `ViewPager` in layout..?? `fragment_new.xml` or `row_list.xml` ..?? and if i am adding in row_list.xml then how use viewPager in Holder and How to set Adaper for ViewPager..???

Comment: you need to add View pager in  fragment_new .xml

Comment: n its bad idea to do nested fragments any reason are you using tab layout in fragments

Comment: Now i added viewPager... please check its correct way or not...

Comment: please check this link https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/ you will get better idea how to use tab layout https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: already saw this tutorial.. but they using each fragment for each tab and they are not using recycler view...

Comment: Hi @RamachandranA I also trying to achieve same look so can you tell me if you fine any solution for that?